# None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied while using Text composable in material 3

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

While using material 3 Text composable, I encounter an error `None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied`. What am I missing?

None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview


@Composable
fun HomeScreen(){
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(Color.Yellow),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ){
        Text(
            text = "HOME",
            fontSize = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            color = Color.Black,
          )
    }
}

@Composable
@Preview
fun HomeScreenPreview(){
    HomeScreen()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
Text(
     text = "HOME",
     style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium,
     color = Color.Black,
     fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
```

For more info, have a look [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/designsystems/material3).